# Android studio - Start a sound from the beginning each time a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Im trying to repeat a sound each time the function playSound1 is called upon. If it's allready playing it won't start at the beginning. Help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer sound1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound00);
    }

    public void playSound1(View view) {
      sound1.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`seekTo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#seekTo(int)) or `reset()`.